# Handling (Merge) Objects in Reactjs State

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a todo application in reactjs. I am using object in react state for title and task. The issue is whenever I try to merge old state with new one it does not work.

Please check my code below.

```
const [todo, setTodo] = useState({ title: "", task: ""});

const setObj = { title: valueOfTile, task: valueOfTask};

setTodo({...todo , ...setObj});
```

Also how can I iterate through them? This is what I am doing to iterate:

```
{Object.keys(todo).map((data, i) => (
    <div className="main " key={data}>
      <div CLASSNAME="first">
        <h1>{todo.title}</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="second">
        <p>{todo.task}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  ))}
```

I am not sure why I am getting two rows for one added title and task. Check image[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your state with this:

```
const [todo, setTodo] = useState([]);
```

Then, change this

```
setTodo({...todo , ...setObj});
```

with this:

```
setTodo([...todo, setObj]);
```

You don't need to use `spread operator` on `setObj`. Currently you are adding two items to your state. That's why you are getting two rows.

For mapping, you can do something like this:

```
{ todo.map( (data, index) => {
    // Your code
})
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your first question (update state) needs more information, please give complete code.
2. `Object.keys(todo)` will return `["title", "task"]`, so `["title", "task"].map(function())`'s function in `map` will execute twice time, and results render 2 `<div>`.